# Stuck with a growing pop of a species that is no longer present on the planet

Tags: stellaris

Some of my continental humans living on a ocean planet have modified themselves to be better suited to the climate and then some, and became radical xenophobes and militarists due to supposed clashes with vanilla humans (strangely enough, since my vanilla humans are materialists, xenophiles and individualists, so they should have been fist-bumping the new species).

Eventually, all the vanilla humans got tired of the super-humans' nonsense and emigrated, leaving behind one growing human pop, which is stuck at 0 monthly growth, despite a ridiculous surplus of food on the planet. I assume the pop is not growing due to the lack of grown pops of the same species on the planet. Being an individualist empire, I am not able to resettle or purge the pop. Worse, that pop is counted as the last member of a planetary independence movement. What can I do about this pop?

Comment: I'm trying to think if there's some way you could get one of the humans to move back, so there'd be a grown pop, but I got nothing there either.

Comment: @DCShannon I suppose I could terraform the planet to be less hospitable to other species and more hospitable to humans to encourage some of them to leave and open up slots for humans to move in, but I'm hoping there's an easier solution. Actually, that probably won't work as reproduction will likely outpace emigration.

Comment: Could you possibly change forms of government to allow resettling?

Comment: @DCShannon no, empire ethics determine resettlement policy and available forms of government. As far as I can tell, there is no way to change your empire's ethics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this bug is still present as of 1.1. If you're not concerned about achievements, you can use console to kill it:

- open console with `~`
- type `debugtooltip` to enable additional info on tooltips
- find ID of the pop by hovering mouse over it, should be at the bottom of the popup
- type `kill_pop <ID>` into console

Answer (score 5):

If a planet is allowed to go into starvation, any growing pops instead gain a negative growth modifier.  When their total growth hits zero, the potential pop will disappear.

The easiest way to get starvation quickly is to disable all your food production buildings, but be aware that starvation is only calculated on a new month.

You will get a -65% happiness modifier while your pops are in starvation mode, and that will also not go away until a new month rolls over.

Comment: Time to starve some super-humans. Too bad they didn't think to modify themselves to do photosynthesis.

Comment: Doesn't work, food is at -17 but the growth/month is still at 0 and the growth completion counter remains the same after 3 months of no food. I guess the game just doesn't do any food calculations if there aren't any grown pops of the same species.

Comment: @kotekzot That's so messed up it sounds like a bug. I would report that to Paradox.

Comment: I just took a new species in a border war, I'll try this out this evening.